Can someone explain this inductive reasoning question
I am very stuck on what to look for in the following puzzle. As with all puzzles the more you do, more you know what to look for. But I cannot see anything beyond the alternating capitalisation which narrows down the solutions to one of two.
It is given that 9tB9 is the 3rd element in the sequence

Either the next node is 7Me1 or 3Ff6 with 4kL3 being in between the two options above regardless.
Please can someone explain what I should be looking for and why?

Taken from a series of practice questions on inductive reasoning by SHL.

The puzzle attribution points to a company providing HR services, as far as I could tell, so I suspect the puzzle is something they might pose in a live interview. The solution then is probably not something very intricate.
Taking the digits, a pattern is suggested of falling value that wraps from 0 to 99: 26, 17, 99, 71, 43, 36. This ordering of the nodes also respects the alternating capitalization, but leaves the letters as such without meaning for the solution. Such a misdirection is not unprecedented, though.
I would say in the absence of more context, that's as good of an answer as any other.
Side note: I did notice, that some of the letters - y, u, t - also map to numbers on my Android phone keyboard that appear in the puzzle if I long-press the keys, but that might be spurious.
